# How to write nested ternary operator in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I have to write a condition for showing style on my div but I am making some mistake due to which it is not working properly. Please help me to correct this syntax. This is my code

```
<div
style={item.settings && 'backdropSettings' in item.settings ? { 
item.settings.backdropSettings.value.includes('#') ? 
{background:item.settings.backdropSettings.value} :
{backgroundImage: `url(${item.settings.backdropSettings.value})`}
} : null}
> 
</div>
```

Comment: Don't. Use `if/else` instead. It's much clearer.

Comment: Your ternary operator is hard to read/understand. Don't use it. Use simple `if {} else {}` inside call of function

Comment: @Justinas yeah i can write if{} else {} statement. But I want to use ternary operator. So can help me for this. for writing syntax.

Comment: @DheerajKumar `condition ? (condition ? true : false) : (false)`

Comment: @Justinas but during writing my syntax I am making error during writing curly braces. make you help me to make it correct.

Comment: @DheerajKumar You wrap to curly braces `{` - wrap to simple braces `(`: `item.settings ? (item.settings.backdropSettings ? {background: ...} : {backgroundImage: ..} : null)`

Comment: @Justinas thank you so much it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do complicated calculation do not put it in your render , put it before , it's way simpler, that's why you can't see your mistake.

Try something like this (check how it's written though, not sure it's 100% ok)

```js
const getStyle = (item) => {
    if (item.settings && 'backdropSettings' in item.settings) {
        const { backdropSettings } = item.settings;
        
        if (backdropSettings.value.includes('#')) {
            return `backgroundImage:${item.settings.backdropSettings.value}`
        } else {
            return `backgroundImage:url(${item.settings.backdropSettings.value})`
        }
    } 
    return null
}

return(
    <div style={getStyle(item)}>
    </div> 
);
```

This is way more readable and you can find your mistake easily. Hope it helps.